# Correct sockets to be used with 277v light bulbs

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I am a project that requires 277v lighting. I have found medium based light bulbs that are rated to work on a 277v circuit but the not a medium base socket that is rated for usage above 250v. I have contacted bulb manufacturers and no one seems to know the answer. That brings me to believe that it would be fine to use these 277v light bulbs in a 250v socket. Am I right or what am I missing?

Comment: You should probably edit your question to specify which country this lighting will be used in.

Comment: What is the power rating of the socket and what is the power rating if the lighting? One should not exceed the other. Other than that, the voltage rating covers things like dielectric breakdown, which is unlikely to increase that much by 27V... However, I'd be more comfortable finding a socket rated for higher rather than lower.

Comment: What lamps did you find that will work on 277V? Typically 277V lighting is fluorescent or HID.What is this project? Where is it located?

Answer (score 1):

According to the National Electrical Code, the voltage limit on lighting in a dwelling unit (including motels, dormitories, etc) is 120 volts. You are not allowed to use higher voltages for these occupancies.

The only lighting that normally uses 277 volts is flourescent or HID lighting in a commercial or industrial occupancy. The HID lamps in these locations use mogul bases not medium.

The medium based bulbs you are talking about are probably for use in Europe not the US.

Answer (score 0):

277v incandescent bulbs are made for primarily commercial use off of a wye 480v system.  There are porcelain standard base sockets rated for 600v available.  I would recommend using them

Comment: Your proposal violates NEC 210.6(C), which sets out that screw-shell lampholders used on 277V systems must be of the mogul-base type.

Answer (score -2):

You would most likely breach standards by using the sockets and open yourself to be liable in the case of a fault but you would not be remotely likely to increase the chance of an electrical fault caused by the added 27V.